# Convergence of a geometric-harmonic type double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\rho \in(0,1)$, and $\gamma \in (0,1/2)$. How does one show that $$\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i = 1, j = 1, i \neq j}^t \frac{\rho^{|i-j|}}{i^\gamma j^\gamma} \to 0,$$ as $t \to \infty$? I've run some numerical simulations to confirm this, but I'm looking for techniques on how to prove it.

For comparison, in the case of a single sum, we would have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\rho^i}{i^{\gamma + 1/2}} = \text{Li}_{\gamma + 1/2}(\rho) < \infty$ (the polylogarithm function), so $\frac{1}{\sqrt t} \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{\rho^i}{i^\gamma} \to 0$, as $t \to \infty$, by Kronecker's lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping terms by $k:=|i-j|$, we see that the sum equals $$S_{t}(\rho):=2\sum_{k=1}^{t-1}S_{t,k}\rho^k,\quad S_{t,k}:=\sum_{j=1}^{t-k}\frac1{j^\gamma(j+k)^\gamma}.$$

Now, using $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-\alpha}\asymp n^{1-\alpha}/(1-\alpha)$ for $0<\alpha<1$, we get $$\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{2\gamma-1}S_{t,k}=\frac1{1-2\gamma}\implies\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{2\gamma-1}S_t(\rho)=\frac2{1-2\gamma}\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}$$ by [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem). This is more precise than the needed $S_t(\rho)/t\to 0$.